# java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in receiving when wso2esb connect with remote msmq

Tags: remote-access, msmq, wso2-esb

I have connect MSMQ with WSO2 ESB in local enviroment. After connecting with the remote MSMQ I can send a message to it. But when I got data by listen the following error is occuring:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in receiving at
>   org.apache.camel.component.msmq.native_support.msmq_native_supportJNI
>       .MsmqQueue_receiveMessage(Native Method)
>               at org.apache.camel.component.msmq.native_support.MsmqQueue.receiveMessa
>       ge(MsmqQueue.java:51)
>               at org.apache.axis2.transport.msmq.util.MSMQCamelClient.receive(MSMQCame
>       lClient.java:40)
>               at org.apache.axis2.transport.msmq.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTas
>       k.run(ServiceTaskManager.java:218)
>               at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(Native
>       WorkerPool.java:172)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
>       java:1145)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
>       .java:615)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Did you configured wsoesb as documentation states ?

Comment: Sending and receiving use different protocols - probably an RPC-related issue. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic/